# How to link a word to some part of my document?

Tags: google-docs, links

Suppose in my Google Docs document I write the definition of a word.

5 pages later, I write that word. I want to be able to click in that word and the document take me back to the definition, written 5 pages before, just like Wikipedia does when you click in an element of the summary and it takes you down below to the description of that element.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [bookmark](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893) via Insert → Bookmark

[image]

and link to it later in the document with Insert → Link and select the bookmark:

[image]

You should probably give it a more meaningful name than I did, e.g. "Definition: <word>".